# AED is not a supported currency - CurrencyConvertor Python

Tags: python

I am using **CurrencyConverter library** [https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/] in my Django project.

When I add **AED** which stand for **United Arabs emirates DHIRAM**, it shows that it is not a supported currency.

Is there any other code name for **AED** in CurrencyConverter library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do the following

```
>>> from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
>>> c = CurrencyConverter()
>>> c.currencies
{'PLN', 'CZK', 'HKD', 'ROL', 'TRY', 'KRW', 'MXN', 'CHF', 'NZD', 'SGD', 'GBP', 'THB', 'PHP', 'LTL', 'ILS', 'INR', 'HRK', 'SKK', 'BGN', 'IDR', 'RUB', 'LVL', 'CAD', 'CYP', 'ZAR', 'RON', 'AUD', 'NOK', 'TRL', 'CNY', 'JPY', 'EEK', 'MYR', 'ISK', 'USD', 'SEK', 'HUF', 'DKK', 'MTL', 'BRL', 'EUR', 'SIT'}
>>>
```

You will see, that there is neither `AED` currency nor anything `AED` related

The only solution I can think of is using external apis of finance systems (e.g. [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/))

Answer (score 0):

From https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/ which you have linked

> `currencies` is a set containing all available currencies

so you might find all available following way

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()
print(c.currencies)
```

then lookup their meaning. I doubt there will be another name for **United Arabs emirates DHIRAM**